# ImageMagick with Homebrew

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I am installing ImageMagick with Homebrew by doing 
`brew install imagemagick --with-x11`.

Many of the commands like `convert`, `display`, `montage` work  fine but `animate` does not work.

```
$ animate
-bash: /opt/ImageMagick/bin/animate: No such file or directory
```

I've tried using the `--HEAD` flag and also uninstalling using brew and reinstalling but the same error still persist.

Comment: `homebrew` installs binaries (programs) in `/usr/local/bin`, so anything you are running from `/opt` almost certainly has nothing to do with `homebrew`. Try `/usr/local/bin/animate` instead. Also, I assume you have installed XQuartz if you plan to use X11.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `${FORMULA}` used by your homebrew-ed installation:

```
brew edit imagemagick
```

This will open a file in a text editor listing all settings and commands used to build your homebrew-ed ImageMagick.

Do you discover anything in there that may disable the building of `animate`?

---

Also to check:

- Did you run `brew update`?
- Did you run `brew doctor`? Did you follow all recommendations the brew-doctor told you?
- What version of homebrew do you use (`brew --version`)?
- What is the output of `brew --env` and `brew --config`?
- Did you install into a non-recommended directory? Looks like, looking at your attempt to run `/opt/ImageMagick/bin/animate`...

  Did you try `ls -l /opt/local/ImageMagick*/bin/ | grep animate` ?